# How to shrink first widget in QSplitter when adding new one?

Tags: qt

I have a QSplitter with one large widget followed by few small ones. When a new widget is added, the small ones are shrunk below their recommended `sizeHint()` even though the large one still has much more space than its `sizeHint()`.

Can I change this behaviour? Do I need to use `QSplitter::setSizes()` to do that and if so, how to detect that some widget was added/removed/resized?

I want the widgets to be freely resizable, so using `setFixedHeight()` is not an acceptable solution.

For example, I have two widgets with preferred height 200px (first screenshot).
When I add the third one, it takes more than preferred height, shrinking the others even though all could have their preferred height.

[image: Before adding 3rd widget]

[image: After adding 3rd widget]

Comment: Please post [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How can I do it? I have the sample minimal project, but Qt projects consist of multiple files and AFAIK I cannot post attachments here.

Comment: Isolate your problem by removing irrelevant code and post code (and ui file), for example to demonstrate that splitter with buttons layouts just fine I can post just few lines of code that you can run and verify that it works.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really see which part of the code is relevant. There is a widget which returns 200 px for size hint height. A few of them are added to QSplitter. The last added widget takes too much the space from previous ones, as described. It looks like this is just the way QSplitter works.

Comment: My bad, yes, this is how QSplitter works, when you add new widget to splitter, all shrinkable widgets (preferred size policy implies shrinkable) get shrink in accordance to its stretch factor, (sizeHint is irrelevant in this case, only current size and shrink factor used to calculate new size) use `QSizePolicy::Minimum` to enforce minimum size, or distribute space manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `QSplitter::setStretchFactor(index, factor);`. For example set factor=0 for first widget and factor=1 for rest of the widgets.

You can install event filter and filter for `QEvent::LayoutRequest` to  detect that some widget was added/removed, although it can be fired for other reasons too.

Comment: I tried setStretchFactor but it doesn't seem to work. Probably the reason is that the widget is added, there is no extra space to add, but it needs to be subtracted instead.

Comment: Does added widget implement `sizeHint()` and `sizePolicy()`?

Comment: Yes. The widgets generally are set to Preferred. Once the sizeHint of last widget increases, the space is taken from second-to-last. 
For example, we have a container 1000 pixels high, all widgets have 100px minimum height, w1 is (800px height, with 200px from size hint) and w2 is 200px/200px. 
If we add now w3 (100px/100px), the result will be : w1: 800px, w2: 100px, w3: 100px.

Comment: I am accepting this. This was my worst-case scenario - I hoped wise men here may offer something smarter, but apparently that's the only solution.